# Creating a shortcut on Win10 fails accessdenied

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have implemented the creation of a shortcut as defined in this article on Shell Links by MSDN
[MSDN Shell Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/links?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Here is what I implemented

```
 CreateLink - Uses the Shell's IShellLink and IPersistFile interfaces 
          to create and store a shortcut to the specified object. 

 Returns the result of calling the member functions of the interfaces. 

 Parameters:

 lpszPathObj  - Address of a buffer that contains the path of the object,
            including the file name.

 lpszPathLink - Address of a buffer that contains the path where the 
            Shell link is to be stored, including the file name.

 lpszDesc     - Address of a buffer that contains a description of the 
            Shell link, stored in the Comment field of the link
            properties.

HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc) 
{ 
HRESULT hres; 
IShellLink* psl; 

// Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
// has already been called.
hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
{ 
    IPersistFile* ppf; 

    // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
    psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj); 
    psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

    // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
    // shortcut in persistent storage. 
    hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

        // Ensure that the string is Unicode. 
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 

        // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar 
        // for success.

        // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
        hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
        ppf->Release(); 
    } 
    psl->Release(); 
} 
return hres;
```

I call it as:

```
r = CreateLink("c:\\TT\\TT.exe", "C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\TT.lnk", "TT Program");
```

This works great on a WIN7 machine but fails on a WIN10

This is the code line that is failing:

```
hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 

hres == AccessDenied;
```

I have found other system calls that work on a Win7 but fails on Win10 and it usually comes down to some undocumented change.

Has Win10 tightened privileges on the DeskTop?

Any suggestions on addressing this on a Win10 machine?

Thanks.